# Coniferous tree with alternating bunches of short needles (Toronto area)

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

What species of tree is this?

- Location: East of Toronto, zone 6; urban
- Date of photos: May 10, 2022
- Diameter at breast height: ~18 inches
- Height: ~30 ft

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And to help you sufficiently appreciate the excellent answer below, behold — [The Larch](https://youtu.be/H0zVsxUbbjM?t=3) 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short Answer

***Larix laricina***, commonly called **Tamarack** or **American Larch** is a *deciduous* conifer with short-needle-like leaves arranged in bunched [fascicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascicle_(botany)) in a [alternating](http://woodyplantstutorial.nres.illinois.edu/arrangement/index.html) (sometimes [whorled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whorl_(botany))) arrangement around short stems. The tree is the only species of *Larix* native to the Toronto region.

[image]

<sup>*Larix laricina* stem  Source: [UWGB Herbarium](https://www.uwgb.edu/biodiversity-old/herbarium/gymnosperms/larlar01.htm)</sup>

#### Long Answer

This is a **larch tree** in the genus [*Larix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larch).
These *deciduous* conifer trees characteristically have fascicles, or bunches, of short, needle-like leaves arranges in whorls around their stems. They grow in northern forests (deciduous conifer forests, boreal forests, and northern alpine forests) in temperate cold zones. (In fact, larches grow farther North than any other tree species!)

There are 3 North American Species and 9(-11) Eurasian species. Of those 12(-14) species, only 1 species, ***Larix laricina* (Tamarack)** is native to the Toronto region:

- From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larch):

> *Larix laricina* (Du Roi) K. Koch – Tamarack or American larch. Parts of Alaska and **throughout Canada** and the northern United States from the eastern Rocky Mountains to the Atlantic shore.
>
> *Larix lyallii* Parl. – Subalpine larch. Mountains of **northwest United States** and southwest Canada, at very high altitude.
>
> *Larix occidentalis* Nutt. – Western larch. Mountains of **northwest United States** and southwest Canada, at lower altitudes (Pacific Northwest).

[image]

<sup>Range map for *Larix laricina*. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Larix_laricina_range_map_3.png)</sup>

[BONAP](http://bonap.net/Napa/TaxonMaps/Genus/County/Larix) range maps for *Larix* species confirms *Larix laricina* as native to Toronoto, but it also suggests evidence of the European species *Larix decidua* as an exotic.

- We can rule out *Larix decidua* because the bark is neither smooth nor fissured (see [Wisonsin Horticulture](https://hort.extension.wisc.edu/articles/european-larch-larix-decidua/)), the twigs are not gray or yellow (see the NAS Field Guide to Trees<sup>1</sup>), and the needles are neither reaching lengths of 4 cm (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larix_decidua)) nor (from my quick count from your image) achieving clusters of 30-60 needles per fascicle (see [USFS](https://www.fs.fed.us/database/feis/plants/tree/lardec/all.html)).

[***Larix laricina***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larix_laricina), commonly called **Tamarack** or **American Larch**, then, seems like the most likely species.

- Range: Canada (including Toronto ; see above)
- Bark: rough and scaly ([USFS](https://www.fs.fed.us/database/feis/plants/tree/larlar/all.html))
- Leaves: 2-3 cm needles ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larix_laricina)) bunches into fascicles containing 10-20 needles ([USFS](https://www.fs.fed.us/database/feis/plants/tree/larlar/all.html)).
- Twigs: reddish-brown (NAS Field Guide to Trees<sup>1</sup>)

[image]  [image]

<sup>L: *Larix laricina* fascicle with leaves. R: *Larix laricina* stem  Source: [UWGB Herbarium](https://www.uwgb.edu/biodiversity-old/herbarium/gymnosperms/larlar01.htm)</sup>

Your image is just a tad too blurry and my screen a tad too small to see your needle detail. A better image of the needles and an image focused on the bark would only further help to corroborate my answer.

---

<sup>1. Little, E. L. (1980). National audubon society Field Guide to North American Trees: Eastern Region. Alfred A. KNopf, New York.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much! If you click on my photos to zoom in (on a full PC computer screen), are they still to blurry? You might need to click on them a second time...to ***fully*** zoom in.